# Using conditionals and summary functions in R mutate

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, dplyr

I currently have a data frame in R that looks like this

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 Animal

1  2  2  3  5  Dog

2  2  4  3  1  Dog

3  1  4  1  1  Cat

4  5  5  1  3  Cat

5  5  5  5  3  Bird

6  3  3  3  4  Bird
```

Where I used group_by to group the data by animal.
I would like to created a new column V6 that takes column V4, divides the lower values by the higher values, and if that value is smaller than .5 have V6= A and ifelse has V6 = b..
Is there a way do to that using the mutate function with conditional statement in R?
The actual data frame is much larger so I would rather not have to do it manually.
This is what I would like the final data frame to look like

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 Animal V6

1  2  2  3  5  Dog  A

2  2  4  3  1  Dog  A

3  1  4  1  1  Cat  A

4  5  5  1  3  Cat  A

5  5  5  5  3  Bird B

6  3  3  3  4  Bird B
```

And this is what I have started with

```
df %>% mutate(Type = if(min/max < .5)A,
              ifelse, B)
```

But I know this is not correct.
Thank you!

Comment: If you take only column `V4` where `min = 1` and `max = 5` you obtain for all values of `V6 = 1/5` which is 0.2 and so always `A`. Please explain well. Maybe you meant **from** V1 to **V4**

Comment: The `min` and `max` value part is not clear

Comment: I would like to do it by animal, so that the min value of V4 is divided by the max value of V4 for each individual animal, and then V6 has different values for each animal (A or B)

Comment: `dat %>% group_by(Animal) %>% mutate(new = ifelse(min(V4)/max(V4) < 0.5, "A", "B"))`

Comment: I didn't notice the group by as in your original code there was no group

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr` you can try this

```
dat %>% group_by(Animal) %>% mutate(new = ifelse(min(V4)/max(V4) < 0.5, "A", "B"))

#Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
#Groups: Animal

#  X1 V2 V3 V4 Animal new
#1  2  2  3  5    Dog   A
#2  2  4  3  1    Dog   A
#3  1  4  1  1    Cat   A
#4  5  5  1  3    Cat   A
#5  5  5  5  3   Bird   B
#6  3  3  3  4   Bird   B
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was asking for!

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this without `ifelse`

```
 df1 %>% 
   group_by(Animal) %>% 
   mutate(Type= c('A', 'B')[((min(V4)/max(V4)) >=0.5)+1L])
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 Animal Type
#1  2  2  3  5    Dog    A
#2  2  4  3  1    Dog    A
#3  1  4  1  1    Cat    A
#4  5  5  1  3    Cat    A
#5  5  5  5  3   Bird    B
#6  3  3  3  4   Bird    B
```